# Video capture PTP Command for Canon EOS 6D

Tags: android, video-capture

We are writing a software to record video from Canon EOS 6D camera on Android.

As of now, we have been able to capture still images using PTP commands. However, we need to record movie/video using Canon EOS 6D. We are not able to find suitable PTP codes to do the same.

We would like to know the PTP command and the flow for recording video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find this - this should help: https://github.com/felis/PTP_2.0/blob/master/canoneos.h

Comment: Thanks, had figured this out. A brief for anyone else who gets stuck here: Video:

1. Software On Command (DS_MOVIESELECTSWON = 0x9133)
2. setDevicePropertyValue 53532, value=2 (sendDestinationCamera)
3. set Device Property Value 53688, value=4 -> to start
4. To stop,
setDevicePropertyValue 53688, value=0
setDevicePropertyValue 53680, value=2 (D1B0, PTP_DPC_CANON_EOS_EVFOutputDevice)
setDevicePropertyValue 53683, value=0 (PTP_DPC_CANON_EOS_EVFSharpness                0xD1b3)


53532 = PTP_DPC_CANON_EOS_CaptureDestination     0xD11C 
53688 = PTP_DPC_CANON_EOS_EVFRecordStatus        0xD1b8